Bayesian interval estimate for a quantile
This question is around clarification for whether the posterior distribution and posterior predictive distribution can be used to create an interval estimate for a quantile. Consider the following setup:
Let's say I have $X_i\stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for $i=1,...,n$. For sake of argument, I'm not concerned what the form of the prior is but let's assume I place a prior on both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. Now, I can run my MCMC sampler and obtain posterior samples of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ (let's call them $\mu_{*b}$ and $\sigma^2_{*b}$ for which I have $b=1,...,B$ of them). Now, given the distribution of $X_i$, I can obtain posterior samples of, say, the 95th quantile via
$$q_b= \mu_{*b} + z_{0.95}\sigma_{*b}$$
where $z_{0.95}$ is 95th quantile of the standard normal distribution. Furthermore, since this is sample based, I have a distribution for the posterior quantile, and can take quantiles of those posterior quantile samples to get uncertainty interval estimates. So far, so good.
Now, what I am curious to know is if there is a way to do this using the posterior predictive distribution? For example, under the same setup, maybe the posterior predictive distribution is $y_{\text{new}}\sim N(\mu_{\text{new}}, \sigma^2_{\text{new}})$ and so I can simulate $y_{\text{new}}$ values of that distribution and take the 95th quantile to get an estimate of it. However, this estimate comes with no uncertainty quantification like the posterior distribution does. I guess to  sum up my question,

Should the result based on the posterior distribution and the posterior predictive distribution match, and
Should the posterior predictive distribution yield uncertainty estimates (in the form of an interval) for the 95th quantile?


EDIT for clarity:
It seems people are missing the point of my question, but perhaps that is my own fault in maybe not being clear enough. Let me illustrate my point using R code:
> ### Code for generating an estimate of the 95th posterior quantile 
> ### with accompanying 90% credible interval
> 
> ### For sake of example assume I have already done the posterior 
> ### calculations and I have that: 
> 
> ###     p(sigma^2 | X) ~ Gamma(3, 2)
> ###     p(mu | sigma, X) ~ N(200, sigma)
> 
> 
> # Number of posterior samples
> B <- 10000
> 
> # Posterior samples of sigma^2* and mu^*
> sigma2.star <- rgamma(B, 3, 2)
> mu.star <- rnorm(B, 200, sqrt(sigma2.star))
> 
> # Posterior estimate of the 95th quantile and 90% credible interval
> q <- mu.star + qnorm(0.95) * sigma2.star
> mean(q)
[1] 202.465
> 
> quantile(q, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))
      5%      95% 
200.0369 206.0277 
> 
> 
> ### Using the posterior predictive distribution
> ynew <- rnorm(B, mu.star, sqrt(sigma2.star))
> 
> q <- quantile(ynew, prob = 0.95)
> q
     95% 
202.7814 

But as you see, using the posterior predictive I only get one estimate of the value of $q$ but with no credible interval since I there is only one value.

You may want to check on the Nested Sampling algorithm of John Skilling.

@RomkeBontekoe can you give a bit more clarity around why that method is applicable? I don't quite see the connection.

If you’re using an MCMC sampler such as STAN, PyMC, etc, you will have two parameters size and chains, available. It’s typical to use a high size (samples per chain) like 1000 and with a low number of chains like 4. The primary motivation is to ensure that the r-hat is ~1.0 indicating healthy sampler state. But you could also dial up the chain size to say 100. Then simply sort each chain, retrieving the qth element (‘int(1000*0.05)’) is 5th percentile with 1000 samples per chain. Across chains, you estimate the qth percentil.

But no reason that you couldn’t take your chains, aggregate, bootstrap sample, sort and retrieve the qth element n times for an estimate, instead.

@jbuddy_13 nah: that interval will collapse as the number of samples in each chain goes to infinity. It is not an estimator of a credible interval on the quantile. It is good for estimating uncertainty arising from the MCMC estimation procedure, not for estimating uncertainty arising from limited data.

It is indeed possible to form a CI on the quantile of the true data-generating distribution using draws from the data-generating distribution conditional on a parameter setting*. Say we want to estimate the quantile $\alpha$ of $P(X|\mu^{\textrm{true}},\sigma^{\textrm{true}})$.
First, we fix some positive integer $M$ and sample $M$ many points $x^m_{b}$ from $P(X|\mu_b,\sigma_b)$ for each iteration of MCMC $b$ and $m\in\{1,\ldots,M\}$ to generate $B$ many samples, each of the form $\{x^1_b,\ldots, x^M_b\}$.
Subsequently, we form a quantile associated with each MCMC iteration $b$ by computing the $\alpha$ quantile of $\{x^1_b, \ldots x^M_b\}$. Call that $q_b$. Then $\{q_1,\ldots, q_B\}$ gives us a sample from the posterior distribution** on the quantile of interest.
Now we do what we would always do if we have a sample from a posterior and want to calculate an (equi-tailed) credible interval: we calculate two quantiles! It just so happens to be a sample of quantiles that we're calculating the quantiles of but don't let that confuse you. For a 90% CI, we calculate the 0.05 and 0.95 quantiles of $\{q_1,\ldots, q_B\}$ and this gives us the desired credible interval as $M,B\to\infty$.
I should probably mention that this would better be achieved by numerical quadrature than Monte Carlo sampling from the posterior predictive, but that's not what you asked about :)
Using your code:
# Number of posterior samples
B <- 10000
# Sample size to estimate quantile
M <- 1000

# Sample parameters from posteiror
sigma2.star <- rgamma(B, 3, 2)
mu.star <- rnorm(B, 200, sqrt(sigma2.star))

# Generate data from likelihood.
ynew <- matrix(NA,nrow=B,ncol=M)
for (b in 1:B) {
    ynew[b,] <- rnorm(M, mu.star[b], sqrt(sigma2.star[b]))
}

# Calculate approximate sample from posterior distribution of 0.95 quantile.
q_dist <- apply(ynew, 1, function(x) quantile(x, 0.95))

# Extract 90% equitailed credible interval.
quantile(q_dist, c(0.05, 0.95))

* P.S., this is not a posterior predictive, which is rather the distribution of future data with the parameters integrated out.
** Technically, this is not exactly a sample from the posterior on quantiles for finite $M$.

Are your ${x_{b,1},...,x_{b_M}}$ posterior predictive samples?

@JohnSmith I updated my awful notation to hopefully be clearer. Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but I think I detected a bit of confusion in your question about what a predictive distribution is: it's not $P(X|\mu,\sigma)$ I call this the "data-generating distribution conditional on a parameter setting"; rather, the predictive distribution is $\int P(X|mu,\sigma)P(\mu,\sigma) d(\mu,\sigma)$. From the notation in your question, I am assuming that you meant "data-generating distribution conditional on a parameter setting" rather than "predictive distribution", and that's what we sample from here.

You are correct. I was over simplifying the problem to pretend as if I new the values so as to not have to write them out but my notation was a bit abusive as well. I know that I can just plug in the values of the posterior into the liklelihood to be able to take a numerical integration to get the posterior predictive. My point was assume i know how to sample from the posterior predictive, which I do, but how would I use those samples to calculate the, say, 95th quantile with a credible interval around it? I added R code to my question to try to make this point clear.

@JohnSmith Thanks for the code; I've implemented my method in it. I'm pretty sure I'm giving you what you're asking, but let me know if not.

I see, so for every posterior sample $b$, taking many posterior predictive draws $M$, is that correct? If that is the case, how do we choose $M$?

@JohnSmith just to be super clear again, these are not posterior predictive draws, but rather draws from the data-generating distribution conditional on a parameter setting; but otherwise yes that's right. You choose $M$ as big as possible, as it is only a true sample from the posterior on the quantile as $M\to\infty$.

Thanks. I still think you are mistaken though. Taking samples from teh posterior and plugging them into the likelihood and then sampling from that is a Monte Carlo integration technique which yields the draws from the posterior predictive distribution. For example: https://mc-stan.org/docs/stan-users-guide/posterior-prediction.html

@JohnSmith It's a subtle difference: In my notation, each sample ${x^1_b, \ldots, x^M_b}$ considered individually is not from the posterior predictive, because they are conditioned on a particular $\mu,\sigma$. A posterior predictive requires integrating over $\mu,\sigma$. So therefore, if I concatenate all my samples together to obtain ${x^1_1, \ldots, x^M_1, x^1_2, \ldots, x^M_2, \ldots, x^1_B, \ldots x^M_B}$, then that is indeed a sample from the posterior predictive. But to calculate a draw from the posterior over the $\alpha$ quantile, we need to consider a sample for a given $b$.

I see the difference now in what you are saying. Thank you.


if there is a way to do this using the posterior predictive distribution?


Should the result based on the posterior distribution and the posterior predictive distribution match

No, you cannot compute the posterior distribution for the parameter $q=\mu + z_{q} \sigma$, based on the posterior predictive distribution.
As a simple mechanism for a counterexample suppose the following joint posterior
$$\sigma^2 \sim f(\sigma^2)\\
\mu|\sigma^2 \sim N(0,a-\sigma^2)$$
Then the posterior predictive distribution is independent of $f$ and is $$y_{new} \sim N(0,a)$$
However the posterior distribution of $q = \mu + z_{q} \sigma$ is a mixture of multiple normal distributions with different variances and means and is not independent from $f$.
$$q \sim N(z_{q} v, a-v) \\
\text{with $v \sim f(v)$}$$
This example illustrates how the posterior predictive distribution can be unchanged while the posterior distribution of a quantile parameter differs. Therefore the former cannot be used to derive the latter (as it doesn't capture certain changes).


> ### Using the posterior predictive distribution
> ynew <- rnorm(B, mu.star, sqrt(sigma2.star))
> 
> q <- quantile(ynew, prob = 0.95)
> q
     95% 
202.7814 

But as you see, using the posterior predictive I only get one estimate
of the value of $q$ but with no credible interval since I there is
only one value.

What you tried her is combining several confusions. You computed the 95th quantile of the posterior predictive distribution, and that is a lot different from the posterior distribution of the 95th quantile.
Possibly using the 50th quantile, which is equal to the mean parameter makes this more digestible. The posterior predictive distribution is like the distribution of the mean, with in addition the uncertainty about computation of a new sample, they are obviously different.
To make it even more easy to see, consider the sigma fixed. In that case the posterior for the mean is sampled like
mu.star <- rnorm(B, 200, sigma_fixed)

and the posterior predictive distribution would be sampled with an additional variation
y_new <- rnorm(B, mu.star, sigma_fixed)

The mu.star and y_new obviously have a different distribution.

To obtain posterior predictive samples, follow these steps:

Posterior Sampling: Obtain posterior samples of the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Generate Predictive Samples:

For each posterior sample $(\mu_i,~\sigma_i)$, generate a new data point $x_{\text{new}, i}$ by drawing from the distribution:
$X_{\text{new,}i} {\sim} N(\mu_i,~\sigma_i^2)$
Repeat this for each posterior sample to get a set of posterior predictive samples $(X_{\text{new,}1},~X_{\text{new,}2},~...,~X_{\text{new,}N})$.



This process allows you to capture and quantify the uncertainty in the predictions by considering the variability in the parameter estimates.
P.S. For example, with the posterior predictive samples $(X_{\text{new,}1},~X_{\text{new,}2},~...,~X_{\text{new,}N})$, a quantile interval can be easily derived from the histogram of the samples.

Thanks for the answer but this is what I was alluding to at the end of my question. If you follow your scheme you can take take the quantile of $(X_{\text{new},1}, X_{\text{new},2}, ..., X_{\text{new},N})$ but that will be just one value. I want to be able to construct an uncertainty interval around that quantile value. In the way I described with the posterior its quite direct to do that, but with the posterior predictive I don't quite see how to do it.

Suppose the 95% quantile interval for the posterior predictive samples is $(a, b)$. Are you asking for a 95% quantile interval specifically for $a$ and $b$?

No. I want to estimate the posterior quantile, call it it $q$ and then to construct an interval around $q$. So like the 95th is estimated to be 8 with 90% credible interval (4-12).

If I understand correctly, a quantile interval can be easily derived from the histogram of the posterior predictive samples $(X_{\text{new,}1},~X_{\text{new,}2},~...,~X_{\text{new,}N})$. I have incorporated this into my answer above.

@bluepole could you please explain how instead of just saying it can easily be done? I'm not the OP but I think how to do that is the actual question being asked.
